# Using js instead of jquery to focus on input field when click on a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in jquery:

```
$('.selection').click(function() {
    $('#autocomplete').focus();
});
```

How can i run exactly the same code using pure javascript instead of jquery ?

Comment: jQuery isn't a language. What you want to do is replace JavaScript code using a library (jQuery) with JavaScript code that uses the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) directly. (Terminology helps when searching for solutions. :-) )

Comment: Alternative: `document.querySelector('.selection').addEventListener('click', () => document.querySelector('#autocomplete').focus())`

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this, and it will work exactly the same:

```
document.querySelector('.selection').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('#autocomplete').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can search for vanilla js for focus and click events on the net.
You can also use the snippet below.

```js
const selection = document.querySelector('.selection');
const autocomplete = document.querySelector('#autocomplete')

selection.addEventListener('click', function(){
 autocomplete.focus();
})
```

```css
.selection {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}

#autocomplete {
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="selection"></div>

<input id="autocomplete" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getFocus() {         
    document.getElementById("myTextField").focus();
}
```

This indicated in the official documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/focus